# Android Bar Code Reader Functionality

Tags: android

I need to do product bar code scanning.  I would like to know how to integrate this functionality into my own custom app?  Should I write an activity to do this that uses some library?  If so what library?  or could I call an app that already has this capability from within my app?

Answer (score 0):

The Zebra Crossing project is probably a good start. Apache 2.0 License and clients for android, java, and I think ActionScript too.

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/